# Is there a 3rd party control panel to control the start/stop of ColdFusion server?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm looking for a simple control panel which can control the start/stop function of a ColdFusion server. Where can I find good tutorials on CFM, other than adobe.com ?

Comment: As to your second question: http://learncfinaweek.com/

Comment: Also for your second question, easycfm.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by control? I may be oversimplifying your question, but you can stop ColdFusion by typing `net stop "ColdFusion 9 application server"` into the command prompt and you can start ColdFusion by typing `net start "ColdFusion 9 application server"`

You can easily create a `.bat` file to start and stop your ColdFusion server from these commands.

Answer (score 5):

There are command line options for windows, *nix and OSX to start and stop ColdFusion. There are also controls built into CFBuilder via Eclipse. I even found an Eclipse plugin that loads the Windows Services panel into Eclipse, so you can start & stop multiple services from a panel.

Comment: Do you have a link for that plugin? Sounds useful.

Comment: It may be here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipservices/ - I'll try it when I get back to a PC tomorrow

Comment: Looks like that might be the ticket. Thanks @barnyr.

Answer (score 2):

Ok Here I have found a solution to this. You can create a .bat file using "notepad" then convert it to a windows standalone executable using any good bat 2 exe software.

Thecommand to start and stop ColdFusion 10 from Command Prompt are :

```
NET START "ColdFusion 10 Application Server" 

NET STOP "ColdFusion 10 Application Server"
```

If you dont want any hassle of these, then you can download readymade exe I have made - Here's a screenshot of that:

[image]

Here's the download link:
http://www.ziddu.com/download/21101207/ColdFusion10ServerControlPanel.exe.html

Comment: Why do you have to convert your batch file to an executable?  Why don't you just run the batch file?

Comment: It is much better to look. You cant add a Icon and Product Info in a Bat File. Look at the Icon on the Task Bar.

Answer (score 1):

Macs have a program called coldfusionLauncher.app, which is a simple utility to start/stop ColdFusion. It should be at the root of the main ColdFusion directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it still does, but I believe fusion reactor has that capability....i think.

http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fr/